# haystack isn't indexing my multivalue

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack

I'm trying to get a `MultiValueField` to be indexed, but it's just not working. Here is what I have:

```
class Public_PollIndex(SearchIndex):
    text = CharField(model_attr='question', document=True, use_template=True)
    date_created = DateTimeField(model_attr='date_created')
    choices = MultiValueField()

    def get_model(self):
        return Public_Poll

    def prepare_choices(self, obj):
        # For some silly reason we get (u"choice",) instead of just u"choice"
        # So we unpack...
        c = [ str(c) for (c,) in obj.choice_set.values_list('choice') ]
        return c

    def index_queryset(self):
        return self.get_model().objects.filter(date_created__lte=datetime.datetime.now())
```

Then I have in the template:

```
{{ object.question }}
{{ object.date_created }}
{{ object.choices }}
```

Stepping through with the debugger `prepare_choices` DOES return something like `['foo', 'bar']`

But when I look into solr or `Public_PollIndex(Public_Poll.objects.get(id=1)).load_all_queryset()` I don't see the `choices` field indexed, but the other two are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How do you check the `SearchQuerySet`? `Public_PollIndex(Public_Poll.objects.get(id=1)).load_all_queryset()` returns model `QuerySet` instead of `SearchQuerySet`

Try

```
SearchQuerySet()[0].text
SearchQuerySet()[0].choices
```

Also, in the template, render choices in forloop

```
{% for choice in object.choices %}
{{ choice }}
{% endfor %}
```

Furthermore,

```
return obj.choice_set.values_list('choice', flat=True)

# instead of
c = [ str(c) for (c,) in obj.choice_set.values_list('choice') ]
return c
```

Comment: If using elasticsearch,  obj.choice_set.values_list('choice', flat=True)
throws an elasticsearch.exceptions.SerializationError because the returned object is of type QuerySet.  The indexer fails with TypeError("Unable to serialize <QuerySet .... >. Solution: return list(obj.choice_set.values_list('choice', flat=True))