# Django Haystack w/Elasticsearch returns no results using MultiValueField

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I am attempting to index a large, very normalized, government database. The model I want to return from a search contains none of the fields I need indexed, so I have attempted to use MultiValueFields. My searches are yielding 0 results.

How does one see the contents of an elasticsearch index? Is is permissible to have a haystack index that only includes search fields from models other than the model being returned?

from models.py

```
class Person(models.Model):
    per_idn = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    sex_cod = models.ForeignKey(Sex, to_field='sex_cod_val_cod')
    ...

class Name(models.Model):
    name_idn = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    per_idn = models.ForeignKey(Person, to_field='per_idn')
    name_txt = models.CharField()
    ...

 class Birthdate(models.Model):
     bd_idn = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
     per_idn = models.ForeignKey(Person, to_field='per_idn')
     bd_txt = models.CharField()
     ...
```

from search_indexes.py

```
class PersonIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    names = indexes.MultiValueField()
    dobs = indexes.MultiValueField()

def prepare_names(self,obj):
    return [Name.name_txt for Name in Name.objects.filter(per_idn=obj.per_idn)]

def prepare_dobs(self,obj):
    return [Birthdate.bd_txt for Birthdate in Birthdate.objects.filter(per_idn=obj.per_idn)]

def get_model(self):
    return Person

def index_queryset(self, using=None):
    return self.get_model().objects.filter()
```

I previously created a NameIndex and it worked fine, but with over 14,000,000 names for 4.8 millions people, I need to be able to filter on the DOB as well. It would also make life easier to return a person object instead of a name object. I know it seems strange to have multiple names associated with a person, but this is a government database and people often have many aka's.

./manage.py rebuild_index executes fine. I did some debugging and printed the values of name and dob to the console as it was indexing and the correct values are being returned in the prepare functions. When I use the search.html template, I get 0 results, no matter the query.

from ./manage.py shell

```
>>> from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
>>> sqs = SearchQuerySet().all()
>>> len(sqs)
4799561
>>> sqs = SearchQuerySet().auto_query('jones')
>>> len(sqs)
0
>>>
```

from curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/my_index_name/_mapping?pretty=1'

```
{
"my_index_name" : {
"mappings" : {
  "modelresult" : {
    "properties" : {
      "django_ct" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "index" : "not_analyzed",
        "include_in_all" : false
      },
      "django_id" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "index" : "not_analyzed",
        "include_in_all" : false
      },
      "dobs" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "analyzer" : "snowball"
      },
      "id" : {
        "type" : "string"
      },
      "names" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "analyzer" : "snowball"
      },
      "text" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "analyzer" : "snowball"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How does one see the contents of an elasticsearch index? Is is permissible to have a haystack index that only includes search fields from models other than the model being returned?

Comment: Was having the same problem and saw that no answer was posted. Instead of sqs = SearchQuerySet().auto_query('jones') , try sqs = SearchQuerySet().filter.(names='jones')

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667522/haystack-isnt-indexing-my-multivalue?rq=1